# In Lightroom 4, how to apply same title and keywords to multiple photos?

Tags: lightroom, metadata, keywords

In Lightroom 4, how do I apply the same title and keywords to multiple photos?

Alternatively, how do I apply title and keywords of a photo to another set of multiple photos?

Comment: This is a good example of why we ask for only one question per question. You asked 2 questions and got an answer for each and I do believe BobT answered correctly your second one. Maybe a moderator can split this one in two. They are both useful legitimate questions!

Comment: I'm asking the question following the exact use case of mine.  It might appear superficially as two sub-questions, but really, as an organic use case, it is one question for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Lightroom and select the folders containing the images that you want to synchronize in 'Library'.
2. Select the 'master' image (the one with the title and keywords you want to replicate) and then select the images you want to apply the master information to. You'll notice that the master frame stays a little brighter.
3. Click on 'Sync Metadata' at the lower right of the screen and select 'Check None' and then select 'IPTC Status -> Title' and 'Keywords' (and any other info you want synchronized). Click on Synchronize.
4. Of course, if you want to apply title and keyword information to a group of photos but do not have a master photo, you can either enter the information in the 'Sync Metadata' blanks once you've selected the images, or create a master by selecting one of the group, setting the metadata using the menu on the left side of the 'Library' screen, and then synchronizing as described in 1, 2 and 3.

Done

Comment: When selecting other images, doesn't the 'master' one get unselected?

Comment: Actually, no... It seems to stay selected as the master unless you click on another *already selected* thumbnail image. Note that clicking on the thumbnail *border* will deselect everything else. Clicking on the thumbnail *image* will highlight that thumbnail and keep other selected thumbnails selected.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way it to use multiple selection. On Windows that means using CTRL-Click to select more than one image or SHIFT-Click to select consecutive images. Then, you just type in the keywords in the appropriate box on the right panel and press enter.

You can select images by filtering first. If the filer-bar is not visible, press / and then select the criteria you want. Once only images you wish to apply keywords to are shown, press CTRL-A which selects everything. Again type keywords in the keyword box and press enter.

Note that you can also apply the same keywords to all images as they are imported by putting keywords in the keyword box in the Import dialog.